# Cant get result. Relationships (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, relationships

User model:

```
public function followers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Follower', 'f_who');
}
```

Profile Controller:

```
$user_followers = User::with('followers')->find($user_id)->toArray();
```

Result

```
Array
(
[user_id] => 1
[username] => dev
[email] => dev@dev.com
[name] => AdminName
[surname] => AdminSur
[profile_image] => /img/anon1.jpg
[ip] => 127.0.0.1
[pp] => 0
[np] => 0
[followers_count] => 2
[photos_count] => 0
[created_at] => 2014-12-17 12:08:04
[updated_at] => 2015-01-18 21:15:55
[followers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [follower_id] => 1
                [f_who] => 1
                [f_which] => 2
                [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
                [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [follower_id] => 2
                [f_who] => 1
                [f_which] => 3
                [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
                [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            )

    )
```

)

I need to get followers names,surnames,etc (left join users table) in the child "followers" array using relationships. I'm really confused with this relationships. If the question or structure is unclear, tell me i'll try to fix that.

f_who - means the person who is followed.

f_which - the person who is following

if I try belongsToMany relationship like this:

```
public function followers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Follower', 'users')->withPivot('f_who');
}
```

I get:

```
Unknown column 'users.follower_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `followers`.*, `users`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `users`.`follower_id` as `pivot_follower_id`, `users`.`f_who` as `pivot_f_who` from `followers` inner join `users` on `followers`.`follower_id` = `users`.`follower_id` where `users`.`user_id` in (1))
```

It should select `users`.user_id`

Comment: It looks like your `followers` table is a pivot table handling a many-to-many relationship between your users, correct? In that case, you need to use a BelongsToMany relationship.  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: Still no luck. I edited my question for you, take a look please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are followers other users?  If so then simply relate User to User.

Create a method in your User model like so.

```
class User {

    public function followers() {
        // Model, pivot table, id of person being followed, id of person following
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'followers', 'f_who', 'f_which');   
    }
}
```

Query the relation

```
$user = User::with('followers')->find($user_id)->toArray();
```